# Click link below a div that also has a clickable event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that has a clickable event. In this case it's just a `console.log`, below the div I have an `a href` and I would like that when the user clicks on the `div` and not the `a href` it shows the `console.log`, but if the user clicks on the `a href` it opens the link instead of showing the `console.log`.

Is this possible?

```js
$('.top-item').on( "click", function() {
  console.log("div clicked");
});
```

```css
.top-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-item">
</div>

<a href="#">Click me</a>
```

So when `top-item` is clicked show `console.log`, when `a href` is clicked despite being under `top-item` open the link instead of `console.log`.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You need to apply a z-index to both the div and the link, so that the link appears on top of the div.  Otherwise with your position absolute logic, if the div expands over the link, your issue could happen when you think you are clicking the link, but actually the div covers it and receives the click instead.

Comment: @Taplar, I am wondering with current implementation and no `z-index` if this is possible.

Comment: If the div is on top of the link, the div will receive the click.  If the top item should never be clickable, you *could* disable pointer-events with css on the div so the clicks pass through it.  But if you want both to be clickable, then that's a non-starter.

Comment: @Taplar so it's impossible if i want both clickable with `a href` on bottom

Comment: It would be much more difficult, and would involve figureing out some way to know that the click event happend on the page in an X, Y position that would have clicked the link, and causing it to happen logically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/6b5sf4xc/1/

Then u should calculate from coordinates  like below example. U calculte a coordinates  then click placed coordinates then compare

```
$('.top-item').on( "click", function(e) {
    var coor=$("a").position();
  checkCoordinate(coor.left,coor.left+$("a").width(),coor.top,coor.top+$("a").height(),e.pageX,e.pageY);

});

function checkCoordinate(x1,x2,y1,y2,clickx,clicky){
    if(clickx>=x1 && clickx<=x2 && clicky<=y2 && clicky>=y1){
   console.log("a clicked");
  }
    else{
   console.log("div clicked");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, no I need the `a href` to stay under the `top-item`